# Regular expression for Medicare MBI number format

Tags: regex

I'm wondering if someone can help me to create a regular expression to check if a string matches the new Medicare MBI number format.  Here are the specifics in regards to character position and what they can contain.

I'm using Cache ObjectScript, but any language would be helpful just so I can get the idea.

[image]

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for the reply.  I don't have a lot of experience with regex so I'm not sure how to string things together. Would you mind showing me the complete regex for say the first 3 positions?  Then I can probably take it from there.

Comment: @Greg Assuming just the first 3 positions are needed, it would look something like `^[0-9][ACDEFGHJKMNPQRTUVWXY][0-9ACDEFGHJKMNPQRTUVWXY]$`.  Of course you would have to include the patterns for 4 through 11.

Comment: `\d(?![SLOIBZ])[A-Z](?![SLOIBZ])[A-Z\d]\d(?![SLOIBZ])[A-Z](?![SLOIBZ])[A-Z\d]\d(?![SLOIBZ])[A-Z](?![SLOIBZ])[A-Z]\d{2}`?

Comment: @Greg do you have sample strings of valid/invalid examples (obviously you can make these up). Also, what language are you using (or open to using)? The solution may be easier if specific regex engines are used (esp. PCRE).

Comment: I'm using [Cache ObjectScript](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCOS_regexp) so I'm not sure how many advanced options - I'm thinking we don't have access to PCRE.

Comment: First position is 1-9, not 0-9.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `PCRE` is an option, you could leverage subroutines:

```
(?(DEFINE)
    (?P<numeric>\d)                    # numbers
    (?P<abc>(?![SLOIBZ])[A-Z])         # A-Z without S,L,O,I,B,Z
    (?P<both>(?&numeric)|(?&abc))      # combined
)
^                                      # start of line/string
(?&numeric)(?&abc)(?&both)             # in packs of three
(?&numeric)(?&abc)(?&both)
(?&numeric)(?&abc)(?&abc)
(?&numeric)(?&numeric)
$                                      # end of line/string
```

Paste your IDs into the [**demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/wujKff/3) (but don't save it on regex101 or you'll expose those IDs to the public permanently).

---

Of course, it is not a must to use subroutines, it just makes the expression clearer, more readable and maintainable.
*But*, you could very well go for

```
^
\d
(?![SLOIBZ])[A-Z]
\d|(?![SLOIBZ])[A-Z]
\d
(?![SLOIBZ])[A-Z]
\d|(?![SLOIBZ])[A-Z]
\d
(?![SLOIBZ])[A-Z]
(?![SLOIBZ])[A-Z]
\d
\d
$
```

Or condensed (just copy and paste it):

```
^\d(?![SLOIBZ])[A-Z]\d|(?![SLOIBZ])[A-Z]\d(?![SLOIBZ])[A-Z]\d|(?![SLOIBZ])[A-Z]\d(?![SLOIBZ])[A-Z](?![SLOIBZ])[A-Z]\d\d$
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't think I have access (I could be wrong) to PCRE with [Cache ObjectScript](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCOS_regexp) but this will be helpful for future reference.

Answer (score 5):

First position should be 1-9

https://www.cms.gov/Outreach-and-Education/Medicare-Learning-Network-MLN/MLNProducts/Downloads/MedicareCard-FactSheet-TextOnly-909365.pdf

```
\b[1-9][AC-HJKMNP-RT-Yac-hjkmnp-rt-y][AC-HJKMNP-RT-Yac-hjkmnp-rt-y0-9][0-9]-?[AC-HJKMNP-RT-Yac-hjkmnp-rt-y][AC-HJKMNP-RT-Yac-hjkmnp-rt-y0-9][0-9]-?[AC-HJKMNP-RT-Yac-hjkmnp-rt-y]{2}\d{2}\b
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `!` condition (a negative look-ahead) for one of the previous answers:

```
\b[1-9](?![sloibzSLOIBZ])[a-zA-Z](?![sloibzSLOIBZ)])[a-zA-Z0-9][0-9]-?(?![sloibzSLOIBZ])[a-zA-Z](?![sloibzSLOIBZ])[a-zA-Z0-9][0-9]-?(?![sloibzSLOIBZ])[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{2}\b
```

Or, even shorter:

```
\b[1-9](?![sloibzSLOIBZ])[a-zA-Z](?![sloibzSLOIBZ)])[a-zA-Z\d]\d-?(?![sloibzSLOIBZ])[a-zA-Z](?![sloibzSLOIBZ])[a-zA-Z\d]\d-?(?![sloibzSLOIBZ])[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{2}\b
```

Comment: What do you mean by "using ! condition"?

Comment: Instead of specifying which characters should be included you can specify which chars to exclude. 
For example inclusion like [AC-HJKMNP-RT-Yac-hjkmnp-rt-y] can be written as an exclusion (?![sloibzSLOIBZ])[a-zA-Z]

Answer (score -1):

```
public static boolean isValidHICN(String mHICN) {
    String mPatternHICN = "[1-9]{1}[ACDEFGHJKMNPQRTUVWXY]{1}[A-N]{1}[0-9]{1}[ACDEFGHJKMNPQRTUVWXY]{1}[A-N]{1}[0-9]{1}[ACDEFGHJKMNPQRTUVWXY]{2}[0-9]{2}";
    return (mHICN.matches(mPatternHICN));
}
```